# Laravel Планировщик задач, could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, openserver

Laravel 5.6

php 7.1 x64

mysql 5.7x64

В общем все на опенсервере настроено.
решил поучится делать schedule в ларавеле, в опенсервере планировщик запускается и команда выполняется, но вот именно задача прописанная в laravel выкидывает экзепшин

> could not find driver

Отмечу что сайт и работа через консоль команд artisan работает отлично и ошибок не валится не каких, с бд полностью связь устанавливается. В phpinfo() PDO для mysql есть и включен.
Спасите, со вчера уже бьюсь с ней((

Comment: `could not find driver` - не выскакивает просто так, покажите полную картину ошибки.

Comment: ну вот копия что в лог попадает после попытки выполнить команду
https://pastebin.com/tzpupZ0j